# Find X509 Certificate in a collection where issuer name matches a certain value

Tags: c#, iis, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

In my application i need to be able to find certs in a local store that match a certain issuer name.
So, what I was doing before was:

```
LocalStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "My Common Name", True)
```

But since the new certificate server was installed and is using active directory my certificates "Issuer" field has additional attributes (DC values).
Full string looks like this:

```
"CN=My Common Name, DC=MyCompanyDomain, DC=local"
```

This will not let me use Find method as before, and any combination of CN,DC values didnt work for me.

This is what I've tried in ImmediateWindow:

```
?LocalStore.Certificates.Item(0).IssuerName
{System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName}
    Name: "CN=My Common Name, DC=MyCompanyDomain, DC=local"
    Oid: {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid}
    RawData: {Length=85}
    m_distinguishedName: "CN=My Common Name, DC=MyCompanyDomain, DC=local"
    m_oid: {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid}
    m_rawData: {Length=85}
?LocalStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "My Common Name", True).Count 
0
?LocalStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "My Common", True).Count 
0
?LocalStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerDistinguishedName, "My Common Name", True).Count 
0
?LocalStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerDistinguishedName, "My", True).Count 
0
```

Comment: Your code is looking for the _issuer_ name but your "full string" might be the subject name based on you using "My" in it. Perhaps you meant to use `X509FindType.FindBySubjectName`? If not, are you sure the string is the `Issuer` name, not the `Subject` name?

Comment: Certificate Authority is controlled by me, therefore "My". But no, I'm trying to search by "Issuer". I couldnt figure out a way to disable  DC values output in CA, on the old server everything worked ok without DC's

Answer (score 7):

What you probably want is `FindByIssuerDistingushedName`.

`FindByIssuerName` is a case insensitive substring match against the issuer name in forward order with comma separators and no field tagging.  That doesn't make a whole lot of sense as a sentence, so let's take an example.

The normal Windows (and .NET) way of printing things is actually Reversed, so your Issuer Distinguished Name is most likely `DC=local, DC=MyCompanyDomain, CN=My Common Name`.  FindByIssuerName will turn that value into the string `local, MyCompanyDomain, My Common Name`, and then will match if your input is (case insensitively) found anywhere in that string.

- "local, MyCompanyDomain, My Common Name": Yep
- "local, mycompanyDOMAIN, My common name": Yep
- "local": Yep
- "m": Yep
- " ": Yep
- "banana": Nope

`FindByIssuerDistinguishedName`, on the other hand, is a case-insensitive equals against the same string as cert.Issuer returns.  So the string you already have would be a match.

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/f252ef6d695176143aa46b855db5553fb6e44921/src/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/tests/FindTests.cs#L381-L406 shows the behavior-preserving unit tests for FindByIssuerName and FindByIssuerDistinguishedName.

Comment: this all makes perfect sense, but for some odd reason just doesn't wont to work. I've updated the question to show debug info.

Comment: @AnKing Presumably the cert is expired, not yet valid, or not trusted by your user/machine.  If you change `validOnly: true` to `validOnly: false` you should see matches.

Comment: certs were just issued and definetly not expired, but you are correct, switching to false shows them all. But how can I determine the ultimate source of the problem?

Comment: @AnKing Build an X509Chain for the issuer certificate using default options, it will explain all the reasons the cert isn't trusted.

Comment: The Subject properties being searched in Reverse order was the key part for me. Changing my FindBySubjectName string to reverse order and problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer:

```
    public static X509Certificate2 FindExistingSelfSignedCertificate(this CsrDetails csrDetails)
    {
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection;
        var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        var distinguishedName = string.Format("CN={0}, O={1}, OU={2}, L={3}, S={4}, C={5}, E={6}", csrDetails.CommonName, csrDetails.Organization, csrDetails.OrganizationUnit, csrDetails.Locality, csrDetails.StateOrProvince, csrDetails.Country, csrDetails.Email);

        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerDistinguishedName, distinguishedName, false);
        certStore.Close();

        if (certCollection.Count == 1)
        {
            return certCollection[0];
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Note: If you Quick Watch the certStore.Certificates, you can see what you are trying to match.

Supplemental class:

```
public class CsrDetails
{
    /// <summary>X509 'CN'</summary>
    public string CommonName { get; set; }

    // <summary>X509 SAN extension</summary>
    public List<string> AlternativeNames { get; set; }

    /// <summary>X509 'C'</summary>
    public string Country { get; set; }

    /// <summary>X509 'ST'</summary>
    public string StateOrProvince { get; set; }

    /// <summary>X509 'L'</summary>
    public string Locality { get; set; }

    /// <summary>X509 'O'</summary>
    public string Organization { get; set; }

    /// <summary>X509 'OU'</summary>
    public string OrganizationUnit { get; set; }

    /// <summary>X509 'D'</summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>X509 'S'</summary>
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    /// <summary>X509 'G'</summary>
    public string GivenName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>X509 'I'</summary>
    public string Initials { get; set; }

    /// <summary>X509 'T'</summary>
    public string Title { get; set; }

    /// <summary>X509 'SN'</summary>
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>X509 'UID'</summary>
    public string UniqueIdentifier { get; set; }

    /// <summary>X509 'emailAddress'</summary>
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime? NotBefore { get; set; }
    public DateTime? NotAfter { get; set; }

    public CsrDetails()
    {
        this.AlternativeNames = new List<string>();
    }
}
```